# Nest some ListViews in a ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

We know that ListView has a `Header` property that can allow you custom it's header that can be scrolled out of the ScrollViewer area.

However, if there is a`ListView` in each `PivotItem`(let's assume that there are 2 PivotItem) of a `Pivot`, and they share a `Header` which can be also scrolled out of the ScrollViewer area.

The layout in the case can be described in XAML like:

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <StackPanel>
     <Grid x:Name="SharedHeader" Height="200">
       <TextBlock Text="I am a header"/>
     </Grid>
     <Pivot>
       <PivotItem>
          <ListView MaxHeight="1000"/>
       </PivotItem>
       <PivotItem>
          <ListView MaxHeight="1000"/>
       </PivotItem>
     </Pivot>
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Note that `ListView` above supports `IncrementalLoading` so that I limit their `MaxHeight` in case they load all the items.

And I come up with an idea :

> at first, I disable VerticalScrollMode ListView's inner ScrollViewer. And I detect the top distance of Pivot to the outer ScrollViewer. When the pivot reach the top of the outer ScrollViewer, I enable ListView's inner ScrollViewer and disable the outer one.

Howerver, in my solution, because scrolling gestures are belong to two ScrollViewer, I have to lose my finger in one gesture and then do the next one, which results in inelegant effect while scrolling.

Any idea to implement this effect?

Comment: A `Pivot` is generally a **top-level** control, it shouldn't really be inside a `ScrollViewer` at all. See the [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997788.aspx).

Comment: Sometimes Pivot is a great control to host some content which enable you to swipe between them. In fact in my case, the title and the item header of pivot has been removed.